# How can I Launch or move command prompt or terminal at a certain position on the screen using python?

Tags: python, shell, terminal, command-line-interface

I am trying to make a CLI game in python. I have managed to do resize on both Interfaces :

```
def set_screen_res(width,height):
    __screen_height = height
    __screen_width = width
    if os.name == 'nt' :
        os.system(f'mode con cols={__screen_width} lines={__screen_height}')
    else:
        os.system(f"printf '\\033[8;{__screen_height};{__screen_width}t")
```

But one of my problem is that the launching window is not positioned correctly. It may appear at mid-screen or any other place. I am looking for either the python specific solution or the Interface specific solution to position the window to a specific position.

**Also** : I am trying to make the game not depending on extra libraries than in a fresh python installation. So I don't need library dependant solutions. (I know that may sound silly) but I am making these, as a method to learn python more.